# http://localhost:3000/api/forge/designautomation/workitems 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:2 POST

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying out the step by step tutorial of design-automation in Revit, to modify-your-models from learn.autodesk.io . This code worked perfectly fine even a few days back but today I am suddenly facing this error. I tried recreating the entire project sample once again as per the tutorial but this error is not going away. Can anyone explain what is causing it?

**The error log:**

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM7HP2HS8PF1", Request id "0HM7HP2HS8PF1:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Error calling UploadObject: Error while copying content to a stream. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
   at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.UploadObjectAsyncWithHttpInfo(String bucketKey, String objectName, Nullable`1 contentLength, Stream body, String contentDisposition, String ifMatch, String contentType)
   at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.UploadObjectAsync(String bucketKey, String objectName, Nullable`1 contentLength, Stream body, String contentDisposition, String ifMatch, String contentType)
   at forgeSample.Controllers.DesignAutomationController.StartWorkitem(StartWorkitemInput input) in E:\Test-2nd_Attempt\forgeSample\Controllers\DesignAutomationController.cs:line 275
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

DesignAutomationController.cs

```cs
using Autodesk.Forge;
using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation;
using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model;
using Autodesk.Forge.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Activity = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.Activity;
using Alias = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.Alias;
using AppBundle = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.AppBundle;
using Parameter = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.Parameter;
using WorkItem = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.WorkItem;
using WorkItemStatus = Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model.WorkItemStatus;

namespace forgeSample.Controllers {
    [ApiController]
    public class DesignAutomationController: ControllerBase {
        // Used to access the application folder (temp location for files & bundles)
        private IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        // used to access the SignalR Hub
        private IHubContext < DesignAutomationHub > _hubContext;
        // Local folder for bundles
        public string LocalBundlesFolder {
            get {
                return Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "bundles");
            }
        }
        /// Prefix for AppBundles and Activities
        public static string NickName {
            get {
                return OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CLIENT_ID");
            }
        }
        /// Alias for the app (e.g. DEV, STG, PROD). This value may come from an environment variable
        public static string Alias {
            get {
                return "dev";
            }
        }
        // Design Automation v3 API
        DesignAutomationClient _designAutomation;

        // Constructor, where env and hubContext are specified
        public DesignAutomationController(IWebHostEnvironment env, IHubContext < DesignAutomationHub > hubContext, DesignAutomationClient api) {
            _designAutomation = api;
            _env = env;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        // **********************************
        //
        /// <summary>
        /// Names of app bundles on this project
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/appbundles")]
        public string[] GetLocalBundles() {
            // this folder is placed under the public folder, which may expose the bundles
            // but it was defined this way so it be published on most hosts easily
            return Directory.GetFiles(LocalBundlesFolder, "*.zip").Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a list of available engines
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/engines")]
        public async Task < List < string >> GetAvailableEngines() {
            dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();

            // define Engines API
            Page < string > engines = await _designAutomation.GetEnginesAsync();
            engines.Data.Sort();

            return engines.Data; // return list of engines
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Define a new appbundle
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/appbundles")]
        public async Task < IActionResult > CreateAppBundle([FromBody] JObject appBundleSpecs) {
            // basic input validation
            string zipFileName = appBundleSpecs["zipFileName"].Value < string > ();
            string engineName = appBundleSpecs["engine"].Value < string > ();

            // standard name for this sample
            string appBundleName = zipFileName + "AppBundle";

            // check if ZIP with bundle is here
            string packageZipPath = Path.Combine(LocalBundlesFolder, zipFileName + ".zip");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(packageZipPath)) throw new Exception("Appbundle not found at " + packageZipPath);

            // get defined app bundles
            Page < string > appBundles = await _designAutomation.GetAppBundlesAsync();

            // check if app bundle is already define
            dynamic newAppVersion;
            string qualifiedAppBundleId = string.Format("{0}.{1}+{2}", NickName, appBundleName, Alias);
            if (!appBundles.Data.Contains(qualifiedAppBundleId)) {
                // create an appbundle (version 1)
                AppBundle appBundleSpec = new AppBundle() {
                    Package = appBundleName,
                        Engine = engineName,
                        Id = appBundleName,
                        Description = string.Format("Description for {0}", appBundleName),

                };
                newAppVersion = await _designAutomation.CreateAppBundleAsync(appBundleSpec);
                if (newAppVersion == null) throw new Exception("Cannot create new app");

                // create alias pointing to v1
                Alias aliasSpec = new Alias() {
                    Id = Alias, Version = 1
                };
                Alias newAlias = await _designAutomation.CreateAppBundleAliasAsync(appBundleName, aliasSpec);
            } else {
                // create new version
                AppBundle appBundleSpec = new AppBundle() {
                    Engine = engineName,
                        Description = appBundleName
                };
                newAppVersion = await _designAutomation.CreateAppBundleVersionAsync(appBundleName, appBundleSpec);
                if (newAppVersion == null) throw new Exception("Cannot create new version");

                // update alias pointing to v+1
                AliasPatch aliasSpec = new AliasPatch() {
                    Version = newAppVersion.Version
                };
                Alias newAlias = await _designAutomation.ModifyAppBundleAliasAsync(appBundleName, Alias, aliasSpec);
            }

            // upload the zip with .bundle
            RestClient uploadClient = new RestClient(newAppVersion.UploadParameters.EndpointURL);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Empty, Method.POST);
            request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;
            foreach(KeyValuePair < string, string > x in newAppVersion.UploadParameters.FormData) request.AddParameter(x.Key, x.Value);
            request.AddFile("file", packageZipPath);
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            await uploadClient.ExecuteAsync(request);

            return Ok(new {
                AppBundle = qualifiedAppBundleId, Version = newAppVersion.Version
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helps identify the engine
        /// </summary>
        private dynamic EngineAttributes(string engine) {
            if (engine.Contains("3dsMax")) return new {
                commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\3dsmaxbatch.exe -sceneFile \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" $(settings[script].path)", extension = "max", script = "da = dotNetClass(\"Autodesk.Forge.Sample.DesignAutomation.Max.RuntimeExecute\")\nda.ModifyWindowWidthHeight()\n"
            };
            if (engine.Contains("AutoCAD")) return new {
                commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[{0}].path)\" /s $(settings[script].path)", extension = "dwg", script = "UpdateParam\n"
            };
            if (engine.Contains("Inventor")) return new {
                commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\inventorcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[{0}].path)\"", extension = "ipt", script = string.Empty
            };
            if (engine.Contains("Revit")) return new {
                commandLine = "$(engine.path)\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[{0}].path)\"", extension = "rvt", script = string.Empty
            };
            throw new Exception("Invalid engine");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Define a new activity
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/activities")]
        public async Task < IActionResult > CreateActivity([FromBody] JObject activitySpecs) {
            // basic input validation
            string zipFileName = activitySpecs["zipFileName"].Value < string > ();
            string engineName = activitySpecs["engine"].Value < string > ();

            // standard name for this sample
            string appBundleName = zipFileName + "AppBundle";
            string activityName = zipFileName + "Activity";

            // 
            Page < string > activities = await _designAutomation.GetActivitiesAsync();
            string qualifiedActivityId = string.Format("{0}.{1}+{2}", NickName, activityName, Alias);
            if (!activities.Data.Contains(qualifiedActivityId)) {
                // define the activity
                // ToDo: parametrize for different engines...
                dynamic engineAttributes = EngineAttributes(engineName);
                string commandLine = string.Format(engineAttributes.commandLine, appBundleName);
                Activity activitySpec = new Activity() {
                    Id = activityName,
                        Appbundles = new List < string > () {
                            string.Format("{0}.{1}+{2}", NickName, appBundleName, Alias)
                        },
                        CommandLine = new List < string > () {
                            commandLine
                        },
                        Engine = engineName,
                        Parameters = new Dictionary < string, Parameter > () {
                            {
                                "inputFile",
                                new Parameter() {
                                    Description = "input file", LocalName = "$(inputFile)", Ondemand = false, Required = true, Verb = Verb.Get, Zip = false
                                }
                            }, {
                                "inputJson",
                                new Parameter() {
                                    Description = "input json", LocalName = "params.json", Ondemand = false, Required = false, Verb = Verb.Get, Zip = false
                                }
                            }, {
                                "outputFile",
                                new Parameter() {
                                    Description = "output file", LocalName = "outputFile." + engineAttributes.extension, Ondemand = false, Required = true, Verb = Verb.Put, Zip = false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Settings = new Dictionary < string, ISetting > () {
                            {
                                "script",
                                new StringSetting() {
                                    Value = engineAttributes.script
                                }
                            }
                        }
                };
                Activity newActivity = await _designAutomation.CreateActivityAsync(activitySpec);

                // specify the alias for this Activity
                Alias aliasSpec = new Alias() {
                    Id = Alias, Version = 1
                };
                Alias newAlias = await _designAutomation.CreateActivityAliasAsync(activityName, aliasSpec);

                return Ok(new {
                    Activity = qualifiedActivityId
                });
            }

            // as this activity points to a AppBundle "dev" alias (which points to the last version of the bundle),
            // there is no need to update it (for this sample), but this may be extended for different contexts
            return Ok(new {
                Activity = "Activity already defined"
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get all Activities defined for this account
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/activities")]
        public async Task < List < string >> GetDefinedActivities() {
            // filter list of 
            Page < string > activities = await _designAutomation.GetActivitiesAsync();
            List < string > definedActivities = new List < string > ();
            foreach(string activity in activities.Data)
            if (activity.StartsWith(NickName) && activity.IndexOf("$LATEST") == -1)
                definedActivities.Add(activity.Replace(NickName + ".", String.Empty));

            return definedActivities;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Start a new workitem
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/workitems")]
        public async Task < IActionResult > StartWorkitem([FromForm] StartWorkitemInput input) {
            // basic input validation
            JObject workItemData = JObject.Parse(input.data);
            string widthParam = workItemData["width"].Value < string > ();
            string heigthParam = workItemData["height"].Value < string > ();
            string activityName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", NickName, workItemData["activityName"].Value < string > ());
            string browerConnectionId = workItemData["browerConnectionId"].Value < string > ();

            // save the file on the server
            var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, Path.GetFileName(input.inputFile.FileName));
            using(var stream = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create)) await input.inputFile.CopyToAsync(stream);

            // OAuth token
            dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();

            // upload file to OSS Bucket
            // 1. ensure bucket existis
            string bucketKey = NickName.ToLower() + "-designautomation";
            BucketsApi buckets = new BucketsApi();
            buckets.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
            try {
                PostBucketsPayload bucketPayload = new PostBucketsPayload(bucketKey, null, PostBucketsPayload.PolicyKeyEnum.Transient);
                await buckets.CreateBucketAsync(bucketPayload, "US");
            } catch {}; // in case bucket already exists
            // 2. upload inputFile
            string inputFileNameOSS = string.Format("{0}_input_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"), Path.GetFileName(input.inputFile.FileName)); // avoid overriding
            ObjectsApi objects = new ObjectsApi();
            objects.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
            using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileSavePath))
            await objects.UploadObjectAsync(bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS, (int) streamReader.BaseStream.Length, streamReader.BaseStream, "application/octet-stream");
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileSavePath); // delete server copy

            // prepare workitem arguments
            // 1. input file
            XrefTreeArgument inputFileArgument = new XrefTreeArgument() {
                Url = string.Format("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{0}/objects/{1}", bucketKey, inputFileNameOSS),
                    Headers = new Dictionary < string, string > () {
                        {
                            "Authorization",
                            "Bearer " + oauth.access_token
                        }
                    }
            };
            // 2. input json
            dynamic inputJson = new JObject();
            inputJson.Width = widthParam;
            inputJson.Height = heigthParam;
            XrefTreeArgument inputJsonArgument = new XrefTreeArgument() {
                Url = "data:application/json, " + ((JObject) inputJson).ToString(Formatting.None).Replace("\"", "'")
            };
            // 3. output file
            string outputFileNameOSS = string.Format("{0}_output_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"), Path.GetFileName(input.inputFile.FileName)); // avoid overriding
            XrefTreeArgument outputFileArgument = new XrefTreeArgument() {
                Url = string.Format("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{0}/objects/{1}", bucketKey, outputFileNameOSS),
                    Verb = Verb.Put,
                    Headers = new Dictionary < string, string > () {
                        {
                            "Authorization",
                            "Bearer " + oauth.access_token
                        }
                    }
            };

            // prepare & submit workitem
            // the callback contains the connectionId (used to identify the client) and the outputFileName of this workitem
            string callbackUrl = string.Format("{0}/api/forge/callback/designautomation?id={1}&outputFileName={2}", OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL"), browerConnectionId, outputFileNameOSS);
            WorkItem workItemSpec = new WorkItem() {
                ActivityId = activityName,
                    Arguments = new Dictionary < string, IArgument > () {
                        {
                            "inputFile",
                            inputFileArgument
                        }, {
                            "inputJson",
                            inputJsonArgument
                        }, {
                            "outputFile",
                            outputFileArgument
                        }, {
                            "onComplete",
                            new XrefTreeArgument {
                                Verb = Verb.Post, Url = callbackUrl
                            }
                        }
                    }
            };
            WorkItemStatus workItemStatus = await _designAutomation.CreateWorkItemAsync(workItemSpec);

            return Ok(new {
                WorkItemId = workItemStatus.Id
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Input for StartWorkitem
        /// </summary>
        public class StartWorkitemInput {
            public IFormFile inputFile {
                get;
                set;
            }
            public string data {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback from Design Automation Workitem (onProgress or onComplete)
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/api/forge/callback/designautomation")]
        public async Task < IActionResult > OnCallback(string id, string outputFileName, [FromBody] dynamic body) {
            try {
                // your webhook should return immediately! we can use Hangfire to schedule a job
                JObject bodyJson = JObject.Parse((string) body.ToString());
                await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("onComplete", bodyJson.ToString());

                var client = new RestClient(bodyJson["reportUrl"].Value < string > ());
                var request = new RestRequest(string.Empty);

                // send the result output log to the client
                byte[] bs = client.DownloadData(request);
                string report = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bs);
                await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("onComplete", report);

                // generate a signed URL to download the result file and send to the client
                ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi();
                dynamic signedUrl = await objectsApi.CreateSignedResourceAsyncWithHttpInfo(NickName.ToLower() + "-designautomation", outputFileName, new PostBucketsSigned(10), "read");
                await _hubContext.Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("downloadResult", (string)(signedUrl.Data.signedUrl));
            } catch {}

            // ALWAYS return ok (200)
            return Ok();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clear the accounts (for debugging purpouses)
        /// </summary>
        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("api/forge/designautomation/account")]
        public async Task < IActionResult > ClearAccount() {
            // clear account
            await _designAutomation.DeleteForgeAppAsync("me");
            return Ok();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class uses for SignalR
    /// </summary>
    public class DesignAutomationHub: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub {
        public string GetConnectionId() {
            return Context.ConnectionId;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is from a `[Storage API][1]`. I can imagine that it may had a temporary issue. Can you retry to see if it works now?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying. Yes, the problem disappeared the next day. Would you please explain how you identified this problem and how it may be avoided in the future? 
Would you also tell how to identify and resolve similar problems, if they arise in the future?

Sincerely